# cant start MySQL in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

My xampp cant start the MySQL module because the button is grayed out, I've installed the MySQL server but the problem still occur. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Try to open XAMPP control panel as Administrator and then install both services by clicking on the checkbox under service next to `Apache` and `MySQL` after installing you should have something like this
[image]

Check if MySQL is enabled otherwise try to reinstall XAMPP